# servlet url mapping

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, servlet-filters

I have two servlets (MainServlet and LoginServlet) and MainServlet process all request and its mapped to `/*` . LoginServlet process request and it is mapped to /login. I have one html file /html/login.html. Now I want to show this html file when I hit http://localhost:8080/app/login .

In `LoginServlet doGet` method I am doing `httpServletRequest.getRequestDispatcher("login/login.html").include(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);`

but this redirect request to `MainServlet`. I can't change url mapping of `MainSerlvet` from `/*` to something else.

Any Idea how I can achieve above?
PS: If question is not clear please tell me.

Comment: You indicated that your html file is located at "/html/login.html", but it looks like you are getting a request dispatcher for "login/login.html." Is this a typo in your question? Otherwise, this might represent at least part of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You've mapped the `MainServlet` on a global URL pattern `/*` which is a pretty poor practice for servlets (this also covers static resources like CSS/JS/images/etc!). This will also intercept on all forwarded and included requests. You need to map the `MainServlet` on a more specific URL pattern, e.g. `/main/*`, `/app/*` or something like that and create a `Filter` which is mapped on `/*` and forwards all non-`/login` requests to the `MainServlet`.

```
String uri = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURI();

if (uri.startsWith("/login/")) {
    // Just continue to login servlet.
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
} else {
    // Forward to main servlet.
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/main" + uri).forward(request, response);
}
```

By the way, using `RequestDispatcher#include()` to display the view is not entirely correct as well. You should be using `RequestDispatcher#forward()` for this instead.